# Window.Location.Href = Variable set by Selected Radio Button Value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="product" value="Apple"/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="Orange"/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="Grape"/>
```

And two BUTTONS below that will take the user to to different locations

```
<button type="button" id="ButtonHERE">CLICK TO GO HERE</button>
<button type="button" id="ButtonTHERE">CLICK TO GO THERE</button>
```

I want to put a onclick function on ButtonTHERE so that when it's clicked, it triggers a `window.location.href` function and goes to `"shoppingcart.html?value"` where *value* is the value of the selected radio button.

Can I do this ***ALL*** inside the `onclick` of the button, or should I create an outside function when the radio button is clicked, it sets a variable, and then load that variable into the `"shoppingcart.html?value"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do *this ALL inside the onclick of the button* (no jQuery):

```html
<input type="radio" name="product" value="Apple"/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="Orange"/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="Grape"/>

<button type="button" id="ButtonHERE">CLICK TO GO HERE</button>
<button type="button" id="ButtonTHERE" onclick="
  var elm=document.querySelector('input[name=\'product\']:checked');
  if(elm) window.location.href='shoppingcart.html%3F' + elm.value;
">CLICK TO GO THERE</button>
```

You want the `checked` radio-button: to avoid coding a loop (the old way) or a bunch of nested `if`'s (or ternaries) this is the modern and proper way to do that (behind the scenes this still uses a loop tough).
`%3F` is the URL encoding for `?`
Note that you might also need to escape/url-encode the values (depending on characters used)!
There might not be a radio-button selected (a possibility in your current example), then `querySelector('input[name=\'product\']:checked')` will return `null`. So we catch that with the `if` and only redirect when the user selected a radio-button (you can omit that check if you have a default selection that the user can only change, thereby guaranteeing there is a selected radio-button).

Also, you could leave the `href` part of `window.location` as both will work the same.

Finally, note there is a new way since a couple of weeks (I *currently* wouldn't recommend it yet, due to it being so new): [RadioNodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList).
If your radio-buttons are in a form you can grab the form (`elm_form` in this example) and do:

```
elm_form.elements['product'].value
```

to grab the checked value.

PS: it would be better to hook the function using javascript (your question is somewhat vague in that regard):

```
document.getElementById('ButtonTHERE').onclick=function(){
  var elm=document.querySelector('input[name="product"]:checked');
  if(elm) window.location='shoppingcart.html%3F' + elm.value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the radio value and add it to the url:

```
document.getElementById('ButtonTHERE').onclick = function () {
    var val = document.getElementsByName('product')[0].value;
    window.location = "shoppingcart.html?" + val;
};
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('product')[0].value;` will (obviously) consistently return `Apple` which is not what the op wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as:

```html
<input id="asd" type="radio" name="product" value="Apple"/>
<input id="asd" type="radio" name="product" value="Orange"/>
<input id="asd" type="radio" name="product" value="Grape"/>

<button type="button" id="ButtonHERE" 
onclick="window.location.href=('shoppingcart.html?'+(document.getElementsByName('product')[0].checked?document.getElementsByName('product')[0].value:document.getElementsByName('product')[1].checked?document.getElementsByName('product')[1].value:document.getElementsByName('product')[2].value))">CLICK TO GO HERE</button>
<button type="button" id="ButtonTHERE" 
onclick="alert('shoppingcart.html?'+(document.getElementsByName('product')[0].checked?document.getElementsByName('product')[0].value:document.getElementsByName('product')[1].checked?document.getElementsByName('product')[1].value:document.getElementsByName('product')[2].value))">CLICK TO SEE GENERATED LINK</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yup, totally possible. You can write Javascript within the onclick event by doing the following:

```
<button type="button" id="ButtonTHERE" onclick="javascript:window.location.href=('shoppingcart.html?'+document.querySelector('input[type=\'radio\'].product:checked').value)"> CLICK TO GO THERE </button>
```

By adding javascript:, you can execute regular javascript within the event.